# How to include grxml files with UWP application?

Tags: deployment, uwp, speech-recognition

I'm having some difficulty figuring out how to deploy xml grammar files with my UWP application. What I've done is (in Visual Studio) create a new folder in the project's "Assets" folder called "VoiceCommands". To this new folder I intend to add multiple ".grxml" files to be loaded by the UWP application at runtime for speech recognition. What I don't understand is how to tell Visual Studio to bundle up these files with the application so that they are deployed and accessible by the application at runtime, and where will they be stored? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

> What I don't understand is how to tell Visual Studio to bundle up these files with the application so that they are deployed and accessible by the application at runtime, and where will they be stored?

Please check the [Speech recognition and synthesis sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SpeechRecognitionAndSynthesis) and open the project in visual studio. See the **SRGS** folder, all the grammar files are in it. You just need to set the 'Build Action = Content' for each files. These file will be included in your package folder.